# In bash, how can I recursively rename each file to the name of its parent folder, retaining the original extension?

Tags: bash, freebsd

I have a large directory of folders, each of which has only one file:

```
directory/folder1/208hasdfasdf.jpg
directory/folder2/f230fsdf.gif
directory/folder3/23fsdbfasf.jpg

I'd like to rename this to:
directory2/folder1/folder1.jpg
directory2/folder2/folder2.gif
directory3/folder3/folder3.jpg
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

For the path and filenames shown, you can use a loop and combination of `find` and `sed` to make the substitutions, e.g.

```sh
for f in $(find directory -type f -wholename "*folder*"); do
    mv "$f" $(sed -E 's|^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)[.](.*)$|\1/\2/\2.\4|' <<< "$f")
done
```

Where `sed -E 's|^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)[.](.*)$|\1/\2/\2.\4|` uses the alternative delimiter `'|'` instead of `'/'` to ease dealing with pathnames, and then separates and captures the `"directory"` with `^([^/]+)` and then the `"folderX"` with  `([^/]+)`, followed by the filename without the extension `([^.]+)` and lastly the extension `(.*)$` making each component available through the numbered backreferences `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, and `\4`, respectively.

Then to form the new filename, you just duplicate the `\2` foldername in place of the `\3` filename, for a new filename of `\1/\2/\2.\4`

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ find tmp-david -type f -wholename "*folder*"
tmp-david/folder3/23fsdbfasf.jpg
tmp-david/folder2/f230fsdf.gif
tmp-david/folder1/208hasdfasdf.jpg
```

And the replacement of the filenames with

```
$ for f in $(find tmp-david -type f -wholename "*folder*"); do 
>  mv "$f" $(sed -E 's|^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)[.](.*)$|\1/\2/\2.\4|' <<< "$f")
> done
```

Resulting in:

```
$ find tmp-david -type f -wholename "*folder*"
tmp-david/folder3/folder3.jpg
tmp-david/folder2/folder2.gif
tmp-david/folder1/folder1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, assuming you're using `bash`:

```
find directory/ \( -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -print | 
while read old; do
  parent=${old%/*}
  base=${parent##*/}
  ext=${old##*.}
  mv $old $parent/$base.$ext
done
```

If you're dealing with filenames that contain whitespace you're going
to need to massage this a bit.

---

Before running this script:

```
$ find directory -type f -print
directory/folder2/f230fsdf.gif
directory/folder1/208hasdfasdf.jpg
directory/folder3/23fsdbfasf.jpg
```

After running this script:

```
$ find directory -type f -print
directory/folder2/folder2.gif
directory/folder1/folder1.jpg
directory/folder3/folder3.jpg
```